# Is there any mathematical reason why the mean provided to a normal distribution needs to be arithmetic?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am writing a program to simulate the growth of a person's investment subject to the different monetary obligations they may have. I understand that the best way to think about the "average" investment return is the geometric mean. In a loop over the number of years of the investment's growth, I would like to generate a random value of that year's investment return. I was thinking to provide the geometric mean and the standard deviations of the return to a normal distribution function to get the value.

In the docs for that normal distribution function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) I see it says the mean parameter should be the arithmetic mean. Is there a reason why it would be invalid to give the geometric mean instead?

Comment: For what you're working on, approximate the logarithm of the factor by which the investment's value scales as having a Normal distribution, i.e. said factor as having a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a series of observed percentage return rates and want to describe them with a distribution. The first step is to check if those values are normally distributed or not. If they are, the observed distribution has some observed mean and some observed variance. The mean of the observed distribution obviously cannot simultaneously be both the arithmetic and the geometric mean of the values. You can make a normal distribution centered at any value you want, the question is whether that reflects reality in any way.

Answer (score 1):

The central limit theorem states that if you take enough identically distributed variables, their arithmetic sum (or arithmetic mean) converges to a normal distribution regardless of their original distribution. There is no such "easy" theorem for a geometric mean that helps you to model it as a normal distribution.

There is a way around it though.

Consider applying the transformation $y_i = \log(x_i)$.

Than we find:
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i) = \log\left((\prod_{i=1}^n x_i)^\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

So the arithmetic mean of log transformed variables is equal to the $log$ of the non-transformed variables. Luckily, if you assume that this transformed variable is normally distributed with some kind of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then the original variable is [lognormally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with the same $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

What you can do now is:

1. Do the transformation.
2. Compute the mean and sample standard deviation of the transformed variables $y_i$.
3. Apply the central limit theorem, to find $\mathcal{N}(\mu_{y}, \sigma_y / \sqrt{n})$
4. Convert this normal distribution "back" to the distribution on $x_i$, distribution to a lognormal distribution: $LN(\mu_y,\sigma_y / \sqrt{n})$.

p.s. I don't know from your description on whether you need the $\sqrt{n}$ part, but this transformation to a lognormal distribution seems logical if the geometric mean is important.